# Auditing Existing Socket Connection

Tags: injection, ports

Is there any way to interact with a program's socket traffic without installing Winpcap?

I understand that the one listening program per port is a restriction regarding TCP/IP, but I guess I'm more asking whether or not it is still safe from code injected into the program or something similar.

I figure a situation probably calls more for intercepting traffic through MITM or something, I'm just interested in how "low-level" this port rule applies.

Comment: It is possible for [Windows to share TCP/IP ports in certain situations](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/25430/396)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcpdump for TCP/IP sockets

Unix domain sockets are something else.

Comment: So tcpdump will listen to traffic on an occupied port? (As opposed to listening on a port and occupying it)

Answer (score 1):

Firewalls interact with all port traffic and an (H)IDS audits port traffic, too. Neither of those things uses winpcap.

Comment: Firewalls/IDS's on the computer being tested, right? I said something quick about "MITM", but it'd be similar to an intermediary assuming that was what you were referring to.

Comment: Each computer can have a firewall and (H)IDS, and those things listen to all traffic. So, a web server can be listening to port 80 and at the same time have firewall/IDS inspecting port 80 traffic, all on the same computer. The trick is that the traffic is not 'destined' for the firewall/IDS.