# How should I audit and monitor shared TCP ports in Windows?

Tags: windows, ports, monitoring

Windows has a feature called [.NET TCP Port Sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734772%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which allows different .NET applications to share the same TCP/IP port.

I would like to monitor the source and destination connections of each client and associate them to the relevant server side listener.  How do I reliably & efficiently accomplish this?

Comment: First time I've come across this `net.tcp` thing (not being a windows user). It sounds like a nightmare anti-pattern. Thanks microsoft.

Comment: Can you request that it is reported to your systems by in-app code?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93162/obtaining-client-ip-address-in-wcf-3-0

Comment: netstat on the server to determine host IP and source port along with the binary/PID serving the request?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only real audit you can do here is to actually turn the service off. Besides that I think the only limit you can set are the authorized security identifiers (SIDs) which can be configured (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa702669%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on msdn).